# Can I get value from content dictionary with xpath?

Tags: html, dictionary, xpath

This is an example of a meta tag from which I want to get the `pub_date`:

`<meta name="parsely-page" content='{"title":"Article title","link":"https:\/\/site.com\/category\/article","type":"post","section":"category","image_url":"","author":null,"pub_date":"2009-03-01T14:17:14+00:00","post_id":"article_6463676334","tags":[]}' />`

The xpath to get the entire content would be:

`//meta[@name="parsely-author"]/@content`

Is it possible to get the values of dict keys using xpath?

Answer (score 1):

With XPath 3.1 you can do

```
//meta[@name="parsely-author"]/parse-json(@content)?pub-date
```

Sadly, it's very likely that you are using an XPath processor that only supports XPath 1.0 in which case you won't be able to use this unless you find a different processor.

Answer (score 1):

**With XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vQ">"</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    'substring-before(substring-after(//meta[@name="parsely-page"]/@content,
                                      concat($vQ, "pub_date", $vQ, ":", $vQ)), $vQ)'/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is performed on this XML document** (your meta tag):

```
<meta name="parsely-page"
content='{"title":"Article title","link":"https:\/\/site.com\/category\/article","type":"post","section":"category","image_url":"","author":null,"pub_date":"2009-03-01T14:17:14+00:00","post_id":"article_6463676334","tags":[]}' />
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

2009-03-01T14:17:14+00:00

**We can write a single XPath 1.0 expression that evaluates to the wanted string**, however we will have to escape quotes and apostrophes in order to avoid errors for their being nested, if unescaped:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//meta[@name="parsely-page"]/@content, 
                                 &apos;&quot;pub_date&quot;:&quot;&apos;), 
                 &apos;&quot;&apos;)
```

**Verification using XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vQ">"</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    'substring-before(substring-after(//meta[@name="parsely-page"]/@content,
                                      &apos;&quot;pub_date&quot;:&quot;&apos;), 
                      &apos;&quot;&apos;)'/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the same XML document** (above), it evaluates the single XPath 1.0 expression and outputs the wanted, correct result:

2009-03-01T14:17:14+00:00